# Is it a good practice to edit a class inside a dependency jar?

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a java project. There is a bug inside a dependency that caused an error.

I identified the line of code that caused it. So I unzipped the dependency jar then corrected the java file and compiled it and zipped the dependency into a .zip and changed the extension to .jar.

It worked! It is not a major change, I only casted something. It's com.extgs:gxt by the way.

But is it a good practice? I found no other solution as migrating to a higher version would break all the app and it takes a lot of time to do such work.

Comment: Report the bug to the project so they can fix it.  If you don’t want to maintain your fork (or if you don’t want to confuse a future maintainer) see if you can fix it in your own code e.g. with a subclass

Comment: Simple answer to this. No. Report to maintainers...

Comment: @khmarbaise gxt is no longer maintained, what to do in this case?

Comment: @clorzs fork the source and maintain it.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i searched for the dependency (gxt 2.3.1a-gwt22) source on the net but couldn't find it to commit my edit

Comment: This mean that you have a buggy, Unmaintained dependency that you most likely are the only person in the world who cares about.  You might want to consider either allocating resources to maintain or migrate to something else.

Comment: True, is it old, I am maintaining an old project and we don't have the ressource to migrate to higher versions as we should rewrite almost all the app. I saw devs editing their dependencies on gwt-users forum so I wanted to know if it there's a better practice

Comment: Ah it is a product. Them fixing is what you pay for. https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/Getting_Started.html

Comment: regarding your suggestion a subclass, it is possible to force the class we write instead of the one inside a dependency? The bug comes from the .java and as far as I know shade-plugin works only for replacing .class files

Comment: It is a company's project so paying for support wouldn't be allowed/validated

Comment: `It is a company's project so paying for support wouldn't be allowed` this is to say it clear silly. This means your company relies on it. This means you either need to maintain the code on your own which produces costs or you have to pay someone else to do the work or you have to migrate your project to newer/mantained technology which causes also costs. I would recommend to do the last one because in the end it's safer from a security perspective and also an invest into the future...

Comment: The project is going to be migrated from gWt to another language next year and now I am having this issue due to upgrading gWt which caused this gXt issue. So ressources are allocated to the migration and this upgrading is just to get rid of vulnerabilities. That's why I am searching for a quick workaround to let apps keep running on the new gWt.

Comment: All this extra information should have been present in the original question.

Comment: I have already asked a gwt/gxt but there was no response so I tried to make it short and general..

Comment: Would it be possible to use aspectj and weave in your fix at load/runtime? That way it is at least transparant and you can keep using the original library.

Comment: Yes I see the aspectj available on the repository but never done that, could you please share a tutorial that may helps?